# Wait for completion handler to finish - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, closures, grand-central-dispatch, completionhandler

I am trying to check if UserNotifications are enabled and if not I want to throw an alert. So I have a function `checkAvailability` which checks multiple things, including the UserNotification authorization status.

```
func checkAvailabilty() -> Bool {

    // 
    // other checking
    //

    var isNotificationsEnabled = false
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound], completionHandler: { (granted, error) in

                    if granted {
                        isNotificationsEnabled = true
                    }
                    else {
                        isNotificationsEnabled = false
                    }
                })
            }


    if isNotificationsEnabled {
        return true
    }
    else {
        // Throw alert: Remind user to activate notifications
        return false
    }
}
```

But the completion handler gets called too late. The function already returned `false` and after that the code in the colsure executes.

I tried to put the whole statement `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization()` in a synchronous dispatch queue but this didn't work.

Another approach would be to return from inside the closure but I have no idea how to accomplish that.

Comment: Add a completion handler as a parameter to `checkAvailabilty()` and call it at the end of requestAuthorization's completion handler.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Do not wait**, use a completion handler, for convenience with an enum:

```
enum AuthResult {
    case success(Bool), failure(Error)
}

func checkAvailabilty(completion: @escaping (AuthResult) -> ()) {
    
    //
    // other checking
    //
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound], completionHandler: { (granted, error) in
        if error != nil {
            completion(.failure(error!))
        } else {
            completion(.success(granted))
        }
        
    })
}
```

And call it:

```
checkAvailabilty { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let granted) : 
      if granted {
         print("access is granted")
      } else {
         print("access is denied")
      }
    case .failure(let error): print(error)
    }
}
```

In Swift 5.5 with async/await it does *wait* indeed

```
func checkAvailabilty() async throws -> Bool {
    
    //
    // other checking
    //
    
    return try await UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound])
}
```

And call it:

```
Task {
    do {
        let granted = try await checkAvailabilty()
        if granted {
           print("access is granted")
        } else {
           print("access is denied")
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly! But one question: What exactly does the `@escaping` mean?

Comment: *The closure is passed as an argument to a function and it is invoked after the function returns*, that means the closure is escaping

Comment: So when a closure with the `@escaping` argument gets called, the function in this case `checkAvailability` automatically returns?

Comment: @Codey Sort of.

Comment: Ok thanks, I've read a little bit more about escaping and noescape and think I understand it. But what I don't understand is why is it necessary to mark this closure as escaping?

Answer (score 5):

Yeah. So as you figured what is happening here is that the function returns before the completion handler gets called. So what you want to do is pass an asynchronous callback to the `checkAvailability` function so it will callback once the completion handler is fired.

```
    func checkAvailability(callback: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

    //
    // other checking
    //

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound], completionHandler: { (granted, error) in
            if granted {
                callback(true)
            } else {
                callback(false)
            }
        })
    }
```

you would call this function like so...

```
    checkAvailability(callback: { (isAvailable) -> Void in
        if isAvailable {
            // notifications are available
        } else {
            // present alert
        }
    })
```

Keep in mind that when you go to present the alert you may need to explicitly dispatch the call to the main thread since the completion handler may callback on a different thread. In which case this is how you would want to call the function and present the alert...

```
    checkAvailability(callback: { (isAvailable) -> Void in
        if isAvailable {
            // notifications are available
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                // present alert
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and for your advice to make UI modifications explicitly in the main thread with `DispatchQueue.main.async{...}`

Answer (score 0):

The code block

```
if isNotificationsEnabled {
    return true
}
else {
    // Throw alert: Remind user to activate notifications
    return false
}
```

gets called immediately after the call to `requestAuthorization(options:completionHandler)`.

You should instead display the alert from within the completion handler:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound], completionHandler: { (granted, error) in
    if !granted {
        // Show alert
    }
})
```

Your function `checkAvailability` is no longer synchronously returning a Bool, as the call to `requestAuthorization(options:completionHandler)` is asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesn't solve the problem that I have to return a bool value. That's why I went with the other solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to return two parameters in the completion handler:

```
func checkAvailabilty(completion: @escaping (_ granted: Bool, _ error: Error?) -> ()) {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { granted, error in
        completion(granted, error)
    }
}
```

---

usage

```
checkAvailabilty { granted, error in
    guard error == nil else {
        // An Authorization error has occurred. Present an alert to the user with the error description.
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: error?.localizedDescription ?? "Authorization failed. Unknown error.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
        }
        return
    }
    if granted {
        print("granted")  // authorization was successful
    } else {
        print("denied")  // present alert from the main thread
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Attention", message: "The App needs you to turn on notifications !!!", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            self.present(alert, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```