# Swift 4. Wait for async result of HealthKit HKQuery before continuing execution

Tags: swift, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch, healthkit, completionhandler

Problem is how to wait for an async query on HealthKit to return a result BEFORE allowing execution to move on. The returned data is critical for further execution.

I know this has been asked/solved many times and I have read many of the posts, however I have tried completion handlers, Dispatch sync and Dispatch Groups and have not been able to come up with an implementation that works.

**Using completion handler**
per [Wait for completion handler to finish - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42255446/wait-for-completion-handler-to-finish-swift)

This calls a method to run a HealthKit Query:

```
func readHK() {

    var block: Bool = false

    hk.findLastBloodGlucoseInHealthKit(completion: { (result) -> Void in
        block = true

        if !(result) {
            print("Problem with HK data")
        }

        else {
            print ("Got HK data OK")
        }

    })

    while !(block) {
    }

    // now move on to the next thing ...

}
```

This does work. Using "block" variable to hold execution pending the callback in concept seems not that different from blocking semaphores, but it's really ugly and asking for trouble if the completion doesn't return for whatever reason. Is there a better way?

**Using Dispatch Groups**

If I put Dispatch Group at the calling function level:

Calling function:

```
func readHK() {

    var block: Bool = false
    dispatchGroup.enter()

    hk.findLastBloodGlucoseInHealthKit(dg: dispatchGroup)
    print ("Back from readHK")

    dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        print("Function complete")
        block = true
    }

    while !(block){   
    }
}
```

Receiving function:

```
func findLastBloodGlucoseInHealthKit(dg: DispatchGroup) {

        print ("Read last HK glucose")

        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate, ascending: false)
        let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: glucoseQuantity!, predicate: nil, limit: 10, sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) { (query, results, error) in
            // .... other stuff
            dg.leave()
```

The completion executes OK, but the .notify method is never called, so the block variable is never updated, program hangs and never exits from the while statement.

Put Dispatch Group in target function but leave .notify at calling level:

```
func readHK() {

    var done: Bool = false

    hk.findLastBloodGlucoseInHealthKit()
    print ("Back from readHK")

    hk.dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
        print("done function")
        done = true
    }

    while !(done) {
    }

}
```

Same issue.

**Using Dispatch**

Documentation and other S.O posts say: “If you want to wait for the block to complete use the sync() method instead.”

But what does “complete” mean? It seems that it does not mean complete the function AND get the later async completion. For example, the below does not hold execution until the completion returns:

```
func readHK() {

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).sync {
        hk.findLastBloodGlucoseInHealthKit()
    }

    print ("Back from readHK")

}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You are trying to solve the wrong problem. Embrace the async nature, don't fight it. Instead of getting `readHK` to wait, properly deal with using a completion handler.

Comment: I agree, you should never wait for an async operation.  For one thing if it takes too much time iOS might decide your app has become non-responsive.  Put your app in a known state and wait for the completion. e.g. disable user interaction, show a spinner and a message telling the user what is happening.  Maybe even allow a cancel option.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, please don't fight the async nature of things.  You will almost always lose, either by making an inefficient app (timers and other delays) or by creating opportunities for hard-to-diagnose bugs by implementing your own blocking functions.

I am far from a Swift/iOS expert, but it appears that your best alternatives are to  use Grand Central Dispatch, or one of the third-party libraries for managing async work. Look at [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit), for example, although I haven't seen as nice a Swift Promises/Futures library as JavaScript's [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html).

You can use DispatchGroup to keep track of the completion handler for queries.  Call the "enter" method when you set up the query, and the "leave" at the end of the results handler, not after the query has been set up or executed.  Make sure that you exit even if the query is completed with an error.  I am not sure why you are having trouble because this works fine in my app.  The trick, I think, is to make sure you always "leave()" the dispatch group no matter what goes wrong.

If you prefer, you can set a barrier task in the DispatchQueue -- this will only execute when all of the earlier tasks in the queue have completed -- instead of using a DispatchGroup.  You do this by adding the correct [options](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchworkitemflags) to the DispatchWorkItem.